# Excel Power Query-adding a column in source after grouping and expanding- how do you get that new column to show?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I often work with queries from AS400 and have to add in a column later after I've done all of my PQ steps. If I group and expand the new column never shows up to be able to be expanded. I refresh the data but it's never available to add into the expansion. Anyone have a solution?

Added a field. But it doesn't show up as a choice in Expand after Grouping rows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Bsb.png)

Comment: You probably need to edit your `M Code` directly in the **Advanced Editor** to account for the variable column names.

Comment: Post a copy of the sample data and your code pasted from home..advanced editor...